# Teechart PHP CalcXPosreturning 0

Tags: php, annotations, teechart

I've been trying to use Teechart to draw a couple of graphs for a project. I've managed to draw the graphs just fine. What I am struggling with is annotating specific points on the graph with some labels.

The specific problem is that when I use $chart1->CalcXPos(someIndex); it always returns 0 instead of a value of the pixels. How can I got about resolving this?

```
    $chart1 = new TChart(640,480);

    $varname = new Line($chart1->getChart()); 

    $someYValues = array(2,3,5,7,11,13);
    $theXValues = array(-3,-1,1,3,4,5);

    $i=0;
    foreach($someYValues as $x){
        $varname->addXY($theXValues[$i],$someYValues[$i]);
        $i++;
    }        

    $varname->Setcolor(Color::BLUE()); 
    $chart1->getAxes()->getBottom()->getTitle()->setText("X-axis label (units)"); 
    $chart1->getAxes()->getLeft()->getTitle()->setText("Y-axis label (units)"); 

    $tool=new Annotation($chart1->getChart());
    $tool->getShape()->setCustomPosition(true);

    //$chart1->paint;

    $xvalue = $chart1->getAxes()->getBottom()->CalcXPosValue($theXValues[2]);
    $yvalue = $chart1->getAxes()->getLeft()->CalcYPosValue($someYValues[2]);

    //$xvalue = $varname->CalcXPosValue($theXValues[2]);
    //$yvalue = $varname->CalcYPosValue($someYValues[2]);

    echo $xvalue;
    echo $yvalue;

    $tool->setTop($xvalue);
    $tool->setLeft($yvalue);

    $tool->setText("Random Text ");

    $chart1->render("ecg.png");
```

Comment: could you please add some sample code?

Comment: Sample code has been added. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing a chart repaint before using `Calc*` functions:

```
$chart1->doInvalidate();
```

Comment: You are a champion <3. For future help, how can I reach out to you Yeray? I am unable to register onto Steema forums, and I am using Teechart as part of my coursework.

Comment: Also Yeray, since I have your attention, would you also know how to change format of axis to display decimals?

I've been trying the following:  `$chart1->getAxes()->getLeft()->getLabels()->setValueFormat('#,##0.###');` 
 Unfortuantely the above isn't working and I still get a bunch of  1 1 1 0 0 0 -1 -1 -1 (top to bottom)

Comment: Steema Software offers several [support options](https://www.steema.com/support_options).

Comment: I've added the ticket [#2107](http://bugs.teechart.net/show_bug.cgi?id=2107). As a workaround you could try using the `OnGetAxisLabel` event as shown in the "Axes\OnGetAxisLabel Event" example [here](http://www.steema.com/files/public/teechart/php/demos/Features/index.html). But please, open new questions for different issues.

Comment: Thank you once again Yeray. You are amazing! I shall keep new questions for different issues in mind!